# Re-inserting the same data into a 2D array until the array reaches a certain number of entries

Tags: php

I have a simple foreach loop which enters data in a 2D array:

```
    foreach ($query as $row){

        if (!isset($sites[$row->site])){ $sites[$row->site] = array(); }
        if (!isset($sites2[$row->site])){ $sites2[$row->site] = array(); }

        if ($row->type == 1){
        $sites[$row->site][] = array($row->data1, $row->data2);
        } else {
        $sites2[$row->site][] = array($row->data1, $row->data2);
        }
    }
```

I need a minimum of 20 entries in the array's ($sites and $sites2).

So if the query has lets say 5 rows, I want to reiterate the loop, repeating the 5 existent rows (inserting them inside the arrays) until the arrays reach 20 rows.

Any ideas?

Comment: IF the query has 15 rows, do you still only want 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$rows=0;
$haveDuplicated=false;
while($rows<20){
   foreach ($query as $row){
     if (!isset($sites[$row->site])){ $sites[$row->site] = array(); }
     if (!isset($sites2[$row->site])){ $sites2[$row->site] = array(); } 

     if ($row->type == 1){
       $sites[$row->site][] = array($row->data1, $row->data2);
     } else {
       $sites2[$row->site][] = array($row->data1, $row->data2);
     }
     $rows++;
     if ($rows>=20 && $haveDuplicated) break;
   }
   $haveDuplicated=true;
}
```

Comment: Ty for answering but I belie this does not do what I want. It does the opposite, it limits everything to 20

Comment: I edited... It will stop at 20 if it has already duplicated, but if it hasn't then it will continue adding everything at least 1 time.  Does this make sense?

Comment: The break breaks the for loop so that you don't add rows beyond the 20 if you are entering duplicate rows.  Imagine there are 15 rows in the query.  When you leave the for loop $rows will be 15. So you do the while loop again and enter into the foreach loop again.  If you run all the way through the for loop then $rows==30 which is not what he wants.  So You have to exit the forloop if you have been through it at least 1 time and you have inserted 20 rows.  So yes you do have to break.

Comment: Testing it, ty very much ajon

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you didn't see [`array_pad()`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) yet?

---

**Edit:** Re-reading your question, I don't think this function is helpful, at least not by itself.

I'm quite tired today, and I can't concentrate much, so can you please do me the favour of showing us the expected results as opposed to your faulty(no offence) code?

Comment: Nope, never did. Have mercy, I am a newb:)

Comment: FYI the padding here, will pad it with whatever value you specify, so it will not duplicate the data, if that is actually what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = 0;

for ($i=0; $i < 20; $i++) { 
    if($index >= count($query))
        $index = 0;

    if (!isset($sites[$query[$index]->site])){ $sites[$query[$index]->site] = array(); }
    if (!isset($sites2[$query[$index]->site])){ $sites2[$query[$index]->site] = array(); } 

    if ($query[$index]->type == 1){
        $sites[$query[$index]->site][] = array($query[$index]->data1, $query[$index]->data2);
    } else {
        $sites2[$query[$index]->site][] = array($query[$index]->data1, $query[$index]->data2);
    }
    $index++;

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because if there are more than 20 elements in the query then the additional elements will not be added.  This limits the number of elements at 20.

Answer (score 0):

This will work at all:

```
$row = 1;
while($row == 20){
    foreach ($query as $row){

        if (!isset($sites[$row->site])){ $sites[$row->site] = array(); }
        if (!isset($sites2[$row->site])){ $sites2[$row->site] = array(); }

        if ($row->type == 1){
        $sites[$row->site][] = array($row->data1, $row->data2);
        } else {
        $sites2[$row->site][] = array($row->data1, $row->data2);
        $row++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Merci Victor:) I think it will work - if the array has 15 rows, for the last 5, will the array start from its first value or repeat the last one?

Comment: The while loop needs to have $row<20, because as it is you define $row to be 1 and then you only enter the loop if $row==20 which it clearly isn't.  Also, if the number of rows in the query isn't a factor of 20, then there will be more than 20 elements in this array when you are done.